# How can i add a splash screen in wp7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I am new in Wp7.I am trying to replace default splash screen image of wp7 with my splash screen image.I replaced  my .jpg image with the default image.But it is not working. Please help me in this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make sure you have a SplashScreenImage.jpg in the root of your project, and the build action is set to Content

Comment: Thanks Lewis ..Its working now by setting build action to content